# Are there any better way to remove this typescript code if check?

Tags: angular, typescript, foreach, ngrx

I am going to iterate object array called a.but a can be undefined also.so, I use the 'if' check before iterating the array. but need to know is there any better way to do it?

```
let a =  //a can be undefined or set of obejct
if (a !== undefined) {
  a.forEach(value => {
    console.log(value);
  });
}
```

I tried using `a?.foreach` but then given the sonar issue as `Expected assingment or functional called` .In above way given me complexity issues.

Comment: sonar issue :https://rules.sonarsource.com/typescript/RSPEC-905

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're quite correct that you can use the [optional chaining operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) for this:

```
a?.forEach(value => {
    console.log(value);
});
```

If Sonar is giving you an error for that, it may be that it's out of date and doesn't understand the optional chaining operator, which is fairly new. You might be able to upgrade it, or tell it to ignore this line of code.

You can also just use `if (a)` rather than `if (a !== undefined)`:

```
if (a) {
    a.forEach(value => {
        console.log(value);
    });
}
```

Comment: sonarIssue gave like this:http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/482.

Comment: sonar vs code 'Non-empty statements should change control flow or have at least one side-effect (typescript:S905)'

Comment: @uma - The statement does change control flow. Again, I think Sonar is just out of date here, though it's interesting that it's not a parsing error.

Comment: Thank you , when i used 'if(a)' sonar issue is gone. but when ? , given that sonar issue. i will checkwheather sonar is outdate.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to check the type of `iterable` instead of `a !== undefined`.

```
if (Array.isArray(a)) {
  a.forEach(value => {
    console.log(value);
  });
}
```

Comment: No, this is TypeScript. The OP knows the type is `object[] | undefined`. So all that's necessary is to know that it's not `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are different ways to avoid error if its undefined but I would suggest using [defaultTo](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#defaultTo) method of `lodash` library.

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) library has some pretty cool methods which are really helpful when building any app.

```
import { defaultTo } from "lodash";

let a; // it will have undefined

a = defaultTo(a, []); // setting default to empty array if a is undefined.

a.forEach((value) => console.log(value)); // it would not throw error anymore
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!!a) {a.forEach(value => {console.log(value);});}
```